# Use Div as Link with jQuery Data

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `<div>` that I would like to use as a link.

Is using JQuery's `data` method to attach the URL I want to link to a 'good practice' way accomplish this?

Having a the `<div>` trigger a click event on a nested `<a>` tag was starting to get messy.

Comment: Show us your code and you will get better answers...

Comment: @jtheman pretty straightforward. just like $('#el').data({'url':'www.google.com'});? not like coding is the difficulty, just is it a good way to do it.

Comment: I assume you can't just make the `<div>` an `<a>`?

Comment: @LittleBigBot Unfortunately they are floated and a tags aren't block-level.

Comment: @thomas What's wrong with setting them to `display:block`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative, if the `<a>` is nested within the `<div>` you're talking about:

```
$('#someDiv').click(function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

Though seeing more of your code would help to find the most optimal answer.

Comment: this seems like a good answer. thank you. Also, is that isaac asimov? Upvote!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `data-url` to the `div`, then use jquery to see what the `data-url` on the clicked `div` is and then finally navigate the page to that url using `window.location.href = url;`

HTML:

```
<div id="container" data-url="http://google.com">Click me</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

jQuery:

```
​$('#container').click(function() {
   var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
   window.location.href = url; 
)};​​​​​
```

see working example - http://jsfiddle.net/JfAHp/

Comment: Your JSFiddle link just links to jsfiddle.net.